# How to split a string by special character "\" in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How to split a string by a special character in gradle

ie.

```
String strDomain = "domain\my name"
```

and catch

```
"domain","my name"
```

Comment: The slash in `strDomain` needs to be escaped properly. Use `"domain\\my name"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular Java/Groovy:

```
def strDomain = "domain\\my name"
println strDomain.split("\\\\")
```